# Binding ListView to IQueryable<IGrouping<>>

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, linq-to-sql, igrouping

I'm binding a `ListView` to an `IQueryable<IGrouping<>>` generated using Linq-to-SQL like so:

```
var lineChanges = dcOJ.LineAuthoriserChanges.GroupBy(g => g.tbl_line)
    .OrderBy(ord => ord.Key.tbl_journal.RefNo);

lvLineAuthoriserChanges.DataSource = lineChanges;
lvLineAuthoriserChanges.DataBind();
```

In the markup, I try to reference the `Key` property of the `IGrouping<>` object:

`<td rowspan="2"><%# Eval("Key.tbl_journal.RefNo") %></td>`

However, I get the error:

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler+Group`2[[Online.LinqToSQL.tbl_line, Online, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Online.LinqToSQL.LineAuthoriserChange, Online, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not contain a property with the name 'Key'.
```

I can cast the data item and display the value that way but it seems so unsatisfactory.

```
<%# ((IGrouping<tbl_line, LineAuthoriserChange>)Container.DataItem).Key.tbl_journal.RefNo %>
```

Does anyone have any ideas what is going on? It seems odd that the complaint should be about missing property on a typed object.